# How to get URI / URL segments on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm newbie on Rails. How do I get the 1st or 2nd segment on this URL

```
http://localhost:3000/users/content
```

result

```
1 - users
2 - content
```

I can't find the exact questions regarding this. If this is already ask please remove this question. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1st way:**

```
path_segments = 'http://localhost:3000/users/content'.split("/")
path_segments[-2] # => users
path_segments[-1] # => content
```

In your controller it will be

```
path_segments = request.fullpath.split("/")
```

---

**2nd way:**

Add to your routes something like

```
'/:obj/:act'
```

for example,

```
get '/:obj/:act', to: 'index#act' # index controller, act action
```

After that it will be passed to controller as

```
params[:obj] # users, 
params[:act] # content
```

Comment: ok I need the 1st way -> request.fullpath.split("/")     (I used it in my layout view actually). Thanks! +1

Comment: To pass var from controller you need to use '@' with name, for example `@obj = params[:obj]` and `@obj` will be defined in view